# Date Range Picker

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-bootstrap

Framework which I use (Angular) and ngx-bootstrap 2.0.5

I want to make reactive form and prepare data to send over API.
But I have problem with Data Range Picker component.

Rest API model except JSON data like this.(for example)

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Baily",
  "startDate": "01/01/2018",
  "endDate": "01/06/2018"
}
```

I have prepared all data but when I want to use Data Picker Range I cannot separate date from array to 2 objects. For Example data from the data picker range

```
"range": [
    "2018-06-03T18:51:51.000Z",
    "2018-07-01T18:51:51.000Z"
  ]
```

And I need that data set to 2 object, one in startDate and another in endDate.

Could you please help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

Having

```
"range"= [ "2018-06-03T18:51:51.000Z", "2018-07-01T18:51:51.000Z" ]
```

you can simply

```
{ "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Baily", "startDate": range[0], "endDate": range[1] }
```

Idk why your API requires custom format, insteed of ISO but you will have to convert those dates to API required format - thats relatively easy to google out how to format `Date` objects

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript

```
  Form: FormGroup;

  const r1 = this.Form.get('range').value[0];
  const r2 = this.Form.get('range').value[1];

  const fromDate = new Date(r1);
  const toDate = new Date(r2);
```

HTML

```
  <form [formGroup]="Form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" #drp="bsDaterangepicker" bsDaterangepicker formControlName="range">
    </div>

  </form>
```

Comment: Thank you for this but I create form builder and in that form builder I prepare data like this. 
this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
      firstName: [''],
      lastName: [''],
      startDate: [''],
      endDate: ['']
    });

So that means that I have import new object in form control, Can I avoid add new object to form control?

Comment: You are not preparing anything here, you only defining your form. Obviously you shoulnd not use startDate endDate here as your widget does not support separate bingings. You shoul bind to somerthiing like `dates` and later on when you want to use data thats in form, transform it. Forms are not for modeling data.